# Form widget not bound to a Doctrine2 association?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have a form for creating a new `BroadcastMessage` entity and i need to display a widget of type `<select multiple="multiple">` bound to `excludedUsers` property, **not directly related to a Doctrine2 an association**.

Inside my `BroadcastMessageType` class (inherits from `AbstractType`):

```
$builder->add('excludedUsers, 'entity', array(
    'class'    => 'Acme\MyBundle\Enrity\User',
    'property' => 'username',
    'multiple' => true
));
```

This of course works for **creating a new** `BroadcastMessage`; but on `editAction` i need a complex query to get excluded users. I need to compute excluded users looking for a record in a cross-reference table named `broadcast_message_reference`.

**My question** is fairly simple: where to add this "complex query" in order to get `excludedUsers` property correctly bound to the `<select multiple="multiple">` widget? Inside my `getExludedUsers` method? If yes, how i'm supposed to access the entity repository for that query?

```
class BroadcastMessage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    private excludedUsers;

    public function __costrunct()
    {
        $this->excludedUsers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addExcludedUser(Acme\MyBundle\Enrity\User $user)
    {
        $this->excludedUsers[] = $user;
        return $this;
    }

   public function getExcludedUsers() { return $this->excludedUsers; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think, you need `query_builder` option within your form item definition:

```
$builder->add('excludedUsers', 'entity', array(
    'class'    => 'Acme\MyBundle\Enrity\User',
    'property' => 'username',
    'multiple' => true,
    'query_builder' => function(EntityManager $em){
         // you have an instance of EntityManager so you may build
         // arbitrary QueryBuilder. Just remember to return it
         // for example:

         $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                  ->from('Acme\MyBundle\Enrity\User u')
                  ->where('u.excluded = true');
         return $qb;
    },
    'property' => 'username'
));
```

This is just rough example, but you can find more about entity form type [**here**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved by [Form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html). Create a service for `EventSubscriber` class, inject `EntityManager` and then subscribe for `FormEvents::SET_DATA` event.